# How do I repair the toilet to the floor?

Tags: plumbing, repair, toilet

Any one know how I need to repair my toilet? My dog dislodged it from the flooring. This is a first for me.
It still works. It doesn’t leak or anything. Bolts are still connected. It rocks if it’s sat on.

Comment: If it rocks, it is probably leaking.  A new wax ring is in your near future. Turn off the water, flush, remove any remaining water and the toilet, replace the wax ring and the toilet.

Comment: And tighten the bolts again.

Comment: There’s no water coming from it, even when flushed. It’s still usable, I just don’t  want to bc of its condition.I will try your suggestion. TY.

Comment: The leak right now can be a drip and you will not see it unless directly under the toilet.  In time a small unseen leak can cause damage to the floor.  Rocking of the toilet will let the wax seal leak.  Wax seals are not known for resealing by just tightening the bolts.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll check it out with y’all’s suggestions. I tried to post a picture with the question. I guess it didn’t go through. I’ll try again. I’m new to this forum. Guess I didn’t post it correctly.

Comment: When editing your question, press on the icon with mountain and a dot/sun

Answer (score 3):

The floor flange could have cracked or broken where one or both of the bolts are anchored.

You need to remove the toilet as others have said.  Then take a look at what you are working with. If the flange is broken you will need a [toilet flange repair ring.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-7-in-L-Circle-Round-Stainless-Steel-Ring/50315043?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-50315043-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA2eKtBhDcARIsAEGTG40ckB6lazrEFWG6RYOcvCuX96ejofcMIU_hBpO7bZPzrsksMqlJBfQaAnhXEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Replace the wax seal and reset the toilet.

If you cannot determine what has happened, take clear pictures and post them in your question and we will know more.

Comment: Better for a n00b to use a waxless seal.

Comment: I love the waxless seals.  I only use those, but every time I suggest it someone ridicules them and says they do nothing but leak.  I should have said to use either.   Oh well.